# Unable to update kops cluster - DNS lookup error

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, kubernetes, kops

error doing DNS lookup for NS records for "kubernetes.xxxx.xxx": lookup kubernetes.xxxxxxxx.xxx on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:56154->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout

[image: My inbound rules for master node]

only my kops update cluster throws the following all other commands looks fine

here is my kops validate cluster

> Using cluster from kubectl context: kubernetes.xxxx.xxx
>
> Validating cluster kubernetes.xxxxxx.xxxx
>
> INSTANCE GROUPS NAME          ROLE    MACHINETYPE MIN MAX SUBNETS
>   master-xxx-xxxx-1a    Master  t2.micro    1   1   xx-xxxxx-1a
>   nodes         Node    t2.micro    2   2   xx-xxxxxx-1a
>
> NODE STATUS NAME                      ROLE    READY
>   ip-xxxx-xx-xx-xxx.xxx-xxxxx-x.compute.internal    master  True
>
> Validation Failed Ready Master(s) 1 out of 1. Ready Node(s) 0 out of
>   2.
>
> your nodes are NOT ready kubernetes.xxxxxx.xxx

Comment: im okay to provide additional information too

Comment: Are you call `kops` from the VM inside your VPC, or from somewhere else? I am just trying to understand where you got that error. DNS server `10.0.2.3:53` available only from a VPC network and you are using `compute.internal` DNS zone, which is available only from the same network with your cluster.

Comment: yes i'm trying it from vagrant

Comment: Yes from the VPC or yes from somewhere else?:)

Comment: It's from my local machine I created a vagrant instance and connecting kops from there. It's not a vpc network

Comment: nslookup kubernetes.xxxxxxxxx.xxx returns Server:  10.0.2.3
Address: 10.0.2.3#53

*** Can't find kubernetes.xxxxxxxxx.xxx: No answer @AntonKostenko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a dns issue. I did a nslookup to my name servers and added the IP's to /etc/resolv.conf file

```
nameserver 10.0.2.3
nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
search xxxxxx
search kubernetes.xxxxxx.xxx
```

and when i ran kops update cluster now. It fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need just to add an entry to your /etc/resolv.conf

> nameserver 8.8.8.8

NB : I suppose that you have well configured your NS record, otherwise you can follow this [doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/getting_started/aws.md#configure-dns)

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote in the comment, you are trying to call the command from your VM which is outside of the VPC network.

Looks like in your system you set the DNS server address as `10.0.2.3:53` and it is unavailable, that's why you cannot resolve your zone from the VM.

To fix it, edit your `/etc/hosts` file and set the nameserver address to `8.8.8.8`, for example. 
If your Kubernetes DNS zone is OK, you will be able to resolve it, of course (in case you are using a public DNS zone).

With a private DNS zone, it is pretty the same, but you should set the DNS server address of that zone instead of `8.8.8.8`.

Comment: 10.0.2.3 is Internet Assigned Numbers Authority. Its a global nameserver. I guess my NS records weren't reflecting yet. adding them directly on /etc/resolv.conf actually fixed. It hope the ns records reflect in some time

Comment: 10.0.2.3 is a path of the private IP address range, check RFC - http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1918.txt. It cannot be a "global nameserver", it  just a default DNS address for several systems, include Vagrant.

Comment: @AntonKostenko it doesn't work for me ! 
error doing DNS lookup for NS records for "kops.ucci.uk": lookup kops.ucci.uk on 192.168.1.1:53: read udp 192.168.1.49:50160->192.168.1.1:53: i/o timeout

Comment: I added the line "8.8.8.8        kops.ucci.uk" to my /etc/hosts but I still having the same error message

Comment: ah! I think I solved the pb, I just added nameserver 8.8.8.8 to my /etc/resolv.conf, with thanks